# Air application icon in mac does not accept any file drop to launch itself

Tags: macos, actionscript-3, flash, apache-flex

Double clicking the icon does launche the application but it do not accept files to launch itself.

But in windows same application icon accepts the file and launches it.

I'm using

> NativeApplication.nativeApplication.addEventListener(InvokeEvent.INVOKE,
>   onInvokeEvent);

to start the app if some file is dropped on it. Windows does it, mac does not. Any expertise?

Answer (score 0):

[Flex documentation](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/help.html?content=File_formats_1.html) says:

> **File type association**
>
> To associate your application with public or custom file types on Mac OS X, you must edit the info.plist file in the bundle to set the CFBundleDocumentTypes property. See Mac OS X Developer Library: Information Property List Key Reference, CFBundleURLTypes.